# PC won't boot Windows from second HDD, Linux works however

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, boot, usb-flash-drive

About 6 days ago I bought a new PC, here's [a link to it](https://www.samwise.ro/cumpara/calculator-hp-6200-pro-sff-intel-core-i5-2400-3-1ghz-8gb-ddr3-250gb-10123) and I installed Fedora on it, no problem at all, the installation took about 10-15 mins.
Then 4 days ago I decide to install Windows for games, I pick up a Windows 7 iso flash it to a usb drive with this command:
`sudo dd if=/path/to/iso of=/dev/sdc progress=status conv=fdatasync`

It didn't even show up.
I used the exact same thing when I installed Fedora(also I installed Bunsen Labs succesfully too).

Then I tried with UNetBootin to no avail.

Then I tried the iso inside a Virtual Machine, it worked perfectly.
I switched to a windows XP iso to test if it's the windows version that's the problem but it happened in the exact same way.

My last idea was to add an HDD I had from the old PC and install windows XP on it through the Virtual Machine, you can get access to a HDD from the VM by creating a raw disk.

I installed windowsXP on the HDD and I tried to boot it(it didn't show on grub but by pressing F9 and selecting the HDD it worked), it booted but I received [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZBUz.png).
I selected "Start windows normally" but the PC screen went black then booted Fedora, the same thing happened in "Safe mode" and every other option.

I'm 4 days into this, I run out of options, I read every question related about this subject on this site and on Google, please help.

Comment: I just unplugged the Linux HDD and left only the Windows HDD, the screen just displayed: "No signal" and the PC reboot with the "Start windows normally" dialog.

Comment: Windows 7 will not install on most PC's that are new. Microsoft has told vendors, NO.  Some vendors offer special builds that will run Windows 7 but not all vendors. For Windows 7 and below including XP, you must run in a Virtual Machine. I recommend VMware over Virtual Box for this task.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to try a Windows 10 copy anyway.

Comment: So if I post the above as an answer will you acknowledge it?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 will not install on most PC's that are new. Microsoft has told vendors, NO. Some vendors offer special builds that will run Windows 7 but not all vendors. You have tried and it has not worked.

For Windows 7 and below including XP, you must run in a Virtual Machine. I recommend VMware over Virtual Box for this task.

Since you wish to go to Windows 10 anyway, then on this machine install Windows 10 Pro and then run whatever old operating systems in a virtual machine.